# Codeigniter - passing value to uri segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

My problem is i have this URL/product_id/transaction_num i want to get what is the exact value of the transaction_num in the url. 
this is the sample output http://prntscr.com/c124w2 the value of transaction_num must be the same value in invoice # in that example.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
 $prod_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
 $transaction_num = $this->uri->segment(4);
 $data['order_detail'] = $this->MainModel->view_proditem($prod_id,$transaction_num);
```

**MODEL**

```
public function view_proditem($prod_id,$transaction_num) {

  $this->db->where('product_id', $prod_id);
  $query = $this->db->get('order_detail'); 

  return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your URL is like

```
http://prntscr.com/product_id/transaction_num
```

Then URI Segment should be

```
 $prod_id = $this->uri->segment(1); #product_id
 $transaction_num = $this->uri->segment(2); #transaction_num
```

Comment: what if i have this url let say like this http://prntscr.com/warranty/product_id/transaction_num what should i use or do?

Comment: `$warenty = $this->uri->segment(1);  $prod_id = $this->uri->segment(2); 
 $transaction_num = $this->uri->segment(3);`

Comment: ive tried this but still the same. the problem is i didnt get the value of transaction_num in my view

Comment: is you pass only one then its come to `$this->uri->segment(1);` or use GET

Answer (score 0):

You can use your action arguments:

```
function warranty($prod_id=0, $transaction_num=0){
    $data['order_detail'] = $this->MainModel->view_proditem($prod_id,$transaction_num);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's. But, you can try var_dump($data); in your action maybe your error is below?

Comment: ive already get the value of $prod_id and $transaction_num but the problem is the query the problem is i get different transaction_num when i pass to to the view which i did a foreach to call the transaction_num

Comment: maybe you need $this->db->where('transaction_num', $transaction_num); in your model?

Comment: ive tried it to it gets the transaction_num but the is a problem let say i have item 1 and button 1 then item 2 and button 2 now the problem is if i press the button 2 it gets the product_id but not the item 2 instead it gets the item 1. btw i used foreach in my view. and also put break before the end of foreach coz if i dont put break it will have 2 forms.

Comment: So, do you need second recod (i mean second form data)?

Comment: yea coz i encountered that problem  if i didnt put break before endforeach if i have 2 or more items. if i pressed to button link to warranty form which the link is warranty/product_id/transaction_num . the form will have the same number with the items. let say 3 items then even you press the button for the 2nd item it will get all 3 items and i wil lhave  3 forms

Comment: So, first, to get onli one form you should use ->row() instead ->result() and don't use foreach just $order_detail->product_id in your view. Second, to get one row just use tow ->where(); finctions consecutive in your model, first for $prod_id, second for $transaction_num (i don't know how it cold it your database).

Comment: thanks for helping i did some debugging and some stuff to make it thanks.!